# Ignore empty string when mapping CSV to JSON using Dataweave

Tags: json, csv, mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am mapping from CSV to JSON and some of the CSV fields are showing as "" in the JSON mapping.  How can I get Dataweave to ignore "" and only populate when there is a value?

I have tried skipNullOn but this doesn't work.  Is there another way to do it or do I have to add an when condition around each field?

Seeing this error with the recursive solution:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your situation is very similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924049/how-to-ignore-empty-objects-in-dataweave-mule-esb).  Try using that approach, and modifying the `acceptable` function.

Comment: Hi Ryan.  I am seeing an error with the code in the recursive solution.  Is there something missing?

Comment: It worked when I tried it :) What's the error?

Comment: I've added a screenshot above.  All looks like it should work but dataweave doesn't seem to like it

Comment: The filterKeyValue function needed to return an object instead of a tuple. I updated the other answer. This seems like a change in the language in the past couple of months. I'll add an answer below.

Comment: Turns out it's just a [Studio bug](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/STUDIO-8694).The answer I added will work either way, but I put the linked answer back to the original method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution, adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39938089/1649678). We recursively decide if we want to remove a field from the model, using [match](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-language-introduction#pattern-matching) in the `acceptable` function to remove empty strings, nulls, and empty objects.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

%function acceptable(value) (
    value match {
        :null -> false,
        o is :object -> o != {},
        s is :string -> s != "",
        default -> true
    }
)

%function filterKeyValue(key, value) (
    {(key): value} when acceptable(value) otherwise {}
)

%function removeFields(x)
    x match {
        a is :array -> a map removeFields($),
        o is :object -> o mapObject
            (filterKeyValue($$, removeFields($))),
        default -> $
    }
---
removeFields(payload)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help thats a useful function

Answer (score 1):

here is the sample logic I built (guess, it is what you are looking for). If it doesn't work, give me a sample CSV and the output JSON format you are expecting, I will try to get the logic for you.

> **Sample CSV Input (with one of the value missing in line 3 and 4)**

```
header1,header2
1,value1
2,value2
3,
,value4
```

> **Dataweave**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload map {
    ("headerValue1": $.header1) when $.header1 != '',
    ("headerValue2": $.header2) when $.header2 != ''
}
```

> **Result**

```
[
  {
    "headerValue1": "1",
    "headerValue2": "value1"
  },
  {
    "headerValue1": "2",
    "headerValue2": "value2"
  },
  {
    "headerValue1": "3"
  },
  {
    "headerValue2": "value4"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have four fields and you want to skip city field if null or empty,  you can also modify the dataweave script to below:

%dw 1.0

### %output application/json

{
    person: payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
        firstname: payload01.fname,
        lastname: payload01.lname,
        address: payload01.address,
        (city: payload01.city)  when payload01.city !=null and payload01.city !=''
    })
}